# How to use ngClass with conditional statements

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-class, angular-ng-if

The color of my mat icon element should change dynamically.

```
<mat-icon class="temperature icon" svgIcon="thermometer-alert" matTooltip = {{temp_tooltip}}
          aria-label="Icon that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over"
          [ngClass]= "{
            'safe' : 23 <= temp_tooltip <= 24.5,
            'alarm_lowside' : 21 <= temp_tooltip < 23,
            'alarm_highside' : 24.5 < temp_tooltip <= 26, 
            'critical_lowside' : temp_tooltip < 21,
            'critical_highside' : temp_tooltip > 26
           }" >
        </mat-icon>
```

temp_tooltip value is binded in component.ts

and css have the color styling

```
.safe {
 color: green
}

.alarm_lowside {
    color: yellow
}

.alarm_highside {
    color: yellow
}

.critical_lowside {
    color: red
}

.critical_highside{
    color: red
}
```

it works fine with critical_lowside and critical_highside classes, but not for the other classes. How to correct. Is the way ngClass is defined is it correct?

Comment: Change your condition to this: `temp_tooltip >= 23 && temp_tooltip <= 24.5,` ... do the same for all.

Answer (score 2):

`23 <= temp_tooltip <= 24.5` is not a correct expression in javascript/typescript.

You should find another way to phrase this condition like
`23 <= temp_tooltip && temp_tooltip <= 24.5`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be this:

```
 [ngClass]= "{
        'safe' : temp_tooltip >= 23 && temp_tooltip <= 24.5,
        'alarm_lowside' : temp_tooltip >= 21 && temp_tooltip < 23,
        'alarm_highside' : temp_tooltip > 24.5 && temp_tooltip <= 26, 
        'critical_lowside' : temp_tooltip < 21,
        'critical_highside' : temp_tooltip > 26
   }"
```